# What does [[ -t 1 ]] do?

Tags: shell-script, test

To my understanding, the script below runs if the user is not root by comparing `$EUID` and `0`. Then, it uses `[[ -t 1 ]]` to decide if the script is running in a terminal or not. If it is, it will use sudo to prompt the user for a password. Otherwise, it will envoke gksudo to do so.

```
if (($EUID != 0)); then

    if [[ -t 1 ]]; then
        sudo "$0" "$@"
    else
        exec 1>output_file && rm output_file
        gksu "$0 $@"
    fi

    exit

fi
```

What is `[[ -t 1 ]]` comparing/evaluating?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The test `[[ -t 1 ]]` returns true if File descriptor 1 (STDOUT) is opened on the terminal, otherwise false.

From `help test` in `bash` :

```
-t FD          True if FD is opened on a terminal.
```

Answer (score 5):

```
[ -t 1 ]
```

...or...

```
test -t 1
```

...return true if file descriptor 1 - stdout - is a tty and false otherwise. The same is true of

```
[[ -t 1 ]]
```

...in many shells.